# Python : Access a JSON element

Tags: python, json, list

Here is a sample of my Json file :

```
{ 'data':[{'word':'first_word',
           'vector':[[0.4][0.2][0.8] } ,
          {'word':'second_word',
           'vector':[[0.2][0.65][0.7] }
          ]}
```

I want to access to values of a given word and its vector, and store it in a variable. Here's what I did :

```
with open('./Vectors.json') as json_file:
    data_dict = json.loads(json_file)
    for word in words: 
        vector = data_dict["Data"][0][w]["vector"]
```

It returns to me the following error :

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper
```

Comment: Try `json.load` instead of `json.loads`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel this keeps running without giving me anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#json.load),

[json.loads](http://json.loads) it is used when your json is in a string, bytes or bytearray

```
with open('./Vectors.json') as json_file:
    data_dict = json.load(json_file)
```

you can use a `dict` to map for each word the vector values using a dictionary comprehension:

```
word_vect = {d['word']: d['vector'] for d in data_dict['data']}
```